# Connect to Azure Virtual Machine from mobile phone

Tags: android, azure, virtual-machine, azure-virtual-machine, azure-virtual-network

I´m using RD-Client on my Android/Huawei phone for remoting to the Azure virtual machine. Mobile phones have no static/fixed IP address, so in my VM config, I need to add the new IP that my phone gets. How can I get a "fixed" IP on my phone or solve this in another legit way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could implement a point to site VPN gateway this way your phone could establish a secure connection to the virtual network even though it has a dynamic IP. I'm not sure how much you are trying to do on the desktop, but you can also set up Azure Bastion and get to the Virtual Machine through the Azure Portal. It uses a browser, so it's not as easy to navigate the desktop as using the RDP client, but it'll do the job in a pinch.

Comment: Bastion is a legit solution when you only want to log in to the VM and there is no need for navigation. Good for now, thanks Mike!